# EPPlus C# x axis type "Text axis"

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

I am using EPPlus for creating excel with charts. I am struggling now for 2 days to set the x axis type to "text axis" and not "automatically select...". Can somebody help me how to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Already solved by myself. For everyone who is interested in, following code did the trick:

```
var chartXml = chart.ChartXml;
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXml.NameTable);
var nsuri = chartXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;

nsm.AddNamespace("c", nsuri);
var textNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx/c:auto/@val", nsm);
if (textNode != null)
    textNode.Value = "0";
```